# not showing null item in filter

Tags: excel, pivot, mdx, cube

I'm not able add filtering to null item in excel. I have many items that any item includes fill or null data I want filter items to date and name to items that find out what item has data in month of year. but when I filter month and name of item in pivot table I can to show fill data only when I enable show item with no data in pivot option that show all null data of other item name, I want to show null data of item name selection no other item name, but I can't add filter to show null cell in pivot table pls guide me.

Comment: In its current state this question is too vague. Also you've tagged it mdx but I cannot see any.

Comment: ok I change question to clear text.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating some sort of measure using `mdx`. Functions that might be useful when dealing with `null` are

`IsEmpty`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145507.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

`NonEmpty`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145988.aspx

Sounds like you might need to make use of this also:

`Filter`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146037.aspx

Once you have some `mdx` written add it to your question.

Comment: many thanks for your comment I add Is Empty field but it shows all empty field again I want to show empty field of filter item no all empty field then I add filter it has not effect.